90s / 00s comic about teens finding / fighting to save a magical world
There was a comic series (not a manga) about a boy that either finds a magical world (maybe through a door) or gets pulled into one to save it, and eventually some friends too.
There was a girl (either his girlfriend or a girl that had a crush on the main guy) who got tricked to eat something that cursed her to scorch anything that she touched because a fairy or something was jealous.

Hi, welcome to SF&F!  What format was it published in?

It was a monthly comic series, I used to work at a newsagents and the owner loved comics so we sold a lot so we could read them for free. But this was 20 years ago and I can barely remember what it was, but its niggling the back of my brain

That's a storyline from fairly late in The Books of Magic, a 1990s Vertigo Comics series.
Wikipedia summarizes that storyline as:

With the contest due to take place in Faerie, Molly is transported from the real world and left to fend for herself until it can be arranged. Knowing something of the Fair Folk from her grandmother, Molly knows that if she eats Faerie food she will never be able to return home: touching the ground would wither her and eating real food would starve her, so she would be forced to stay in Faerie. Instead, she attempts to grow her own real food, her efforts attracting the attention of the Faeries, and her stubbornness attracting the ire of Titania: the Queen tricks Molly into eating Faerie food by making her crops grow overnight. The trick backfires, though, as Molly's anger transforms her into "the burning girl", who cuts a swathe of destruction across Faerie with a horse named Prince.


You are my hero!!

Deadlyspud -- if this is the correct answer, please click the checkmark below the voting buttons, to indicate that this is the correct answer and this question has been answered.  Thanks!
